# Wich activation function for DQL

Tags: neural-network, reinforcement-learning, backpropagation, activation-function, q-learning

After many research, I still can't find a neat answer about this question:

1. When I found the loss of my state-action pair. I'm only backpropagating that loss true the network and setting all other output nodes we didn't took an action from with loss = 0. is this right?
2. I'm trying to understand which activation I should use in my hidden layers. I'm inputing numbers between 0-10 and outputting a raw value where no activation function should be applied (this is because we calculate the loss with raw values).

Thnx for helping out!